# Dynamic Data in SOLR (like counts, viewcounts, etc) - NRT vs Redis?

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, redis

We are creating a web application which would contain posts (something like FB or say Youtube). For the stable part of the data (i.e.the facets, search results & its content), we plan to use SOLR.

What should we use for the unstable part of the data (i.e. dynamic and volatile content such as Like counts, Comments counts, Viewcounts)?

Option 1) Redis

What about storing the "dynamic" data in a different data store (like Redis)? Thus, everytime the counts get refreshed, I do not have to reindex the data into SOLR at all. Thus SOLR indexing is only triggered when new posts are added to the site, and never on any activity on the posts by the users.

Side-note :-
I also looked at the SOLR-Redis plugin at https://github.com/sematext/solr-redis

The plugin looks good, but not sure if the plugin can be used to fetch the data stored in Redis as part of the solr result set, i.e. in docs. The description looks more like the Redis data can be used in the function queries for boosting, sorting, etc. Anyone has experience with this?

Option 2) SOLR NRT with Soft Commits

We would depend on the in-built NRT features. Let's say we do soft-commits every second and hard-commits every 10 seconds. Suppose huge amount of dynamic data is created on the site across hundreds of posts, e.g. 100000 likes across 10000 posts. Thus, this would mean soft-commiting on 10000 rows every second. And then hard-commiting those many rows every 10 seconds. Isn't this overkill?

Which option is preferred? How would you compare both options in terms of scalibility, maintenance, feasibility, best-practices, etc? Any real-life experiences or links to articles?

Many thanks!

p.s. EFF (external file fields) is not an option, as I read that the data in that file can only be used in function queries and cannot be returned as part of a document.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice for you to go with redis for data that is changing frequently. One thing to keep in mind about Solr soft commits is that they invalidate some cache data and if you have a lot of it; opening a new searcher and building the new cache may be a bit more time consuming that you like.

Solr is great for full text search and going through data that requires tokenization. It's also pretty quick; however I don't think it is the right tool for this job.

You can also check out this blog post for more info on Solr commits. 
https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/

Per the post:

> Soft commits are about visibility, hard commits are about durability. 
>   The thing to understand most about soft commits are that they will
>   make documents visible, but at some cost. In particular the “top
>   level” caches, which include what you configure in solrconfig.xml
>   (filterCache, queryResultCache, etc) will be invalidated! Autowarming
>   will be performed on your top level caches (e.g. filterCache,
>   queryResultCache), and any newSearcher queries will be executed. Also,
>   the FieldValueCache is invalidated, so facet queries will have to wait
>   until the cache is refreshed. With very frequent soft commits it’s
>   often the case that your top-level caches are little used and may, in
>   some cases, be eliminated. However, “segment level caches”, which
>   include function queries, sorting caches, etc are “per segment”, so
>   will not be invalidated on soft commit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Redis => haven't explored this option
2. SOLR NRT with Soft Commits => It's kind of overkill and inefficient since it will be updating the complete document though only part of the document is updated every time. The more efficient way to handle this is by keeping these dynamic fields (like count, view count, etc) outside the Lucene index. There are two ways to handle this.

   A. Using EFF (external file fields). In the post you have mentioned that:
   `EFF (external file fields) is not an option, as I read that the data in that file can only be used in function queries and cannot be returned as part of a document.` If I'm not wrong, you want these dynamic field's corresponding value in the search response. We can get this by using `field(exteranl_field_name)` in `fl` parameter.

   B. Using docValues.`DocValue fields are now column-oriented fields with a document-to-value mapping built at index time.` DocValues are not part of the Lucene index. We can define these fields as docValue and use the partial update feature to just update these fields.

DocValue => https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/docvalues.html

EFF => https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/working-with-external-files-and-processes.html

Document Update => https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html